# Swift: Transforming an Array of [A, B, B, B, A, B, B, B] into an Array of Hash [ [A: [B, B, B], [A: [B, B, B]] ]

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have 2 kinds of struct, `Header` and `Session`, both conforming to protocol `TimelineItem`.
I have an `Array` composed of `TimelineItem`like this:
`[Header1, SessionA, SessionB, Header2, SessionC, SessionD]`

My need is to group `Session` under related `Header` like this:
`[ [Header1: [SessionA, SessionB], [Header2: [SessionC, SessionD] ]`

I tried using `filter` method to retrieve only `Header` struct, and `split` method to retrieve an Array of `Session` Array. These work fine but I cannot manage how to reconcile both to build my final `[[Header: [Session]]]` object.

Here is my sample code:

```
enum TimelineItemType: String {  
  case Header = "header"   
  case Session = "session"
}

protocol TimelineItem {
  var id: Int { get }
  var type: TimelineItemType { get }
  var startDate: NSDate { get }
}
```

The `Header` struct

```
struct Header: TimelineItem, Decodable, Hashable, Equatable {
  let id: Int
  let type: TimelineItemType = .Header
  let startDate: NSDate
  let text: String

  init?(json: JSON) {
    guard let id: Int = "id" <~~ json,
      let type: TimelineItemType = "type" <~~ json,
      let startDate: NSDate = "startDate" <~~ json,
      let text: String = "text" <~~ json where type == .Header else {
        return nil
    }
    self.id = id
    self.startDate = startDate
    self.text = text
  }

  var hashValue: Int {
    // As id is unique, we can use it for hash purpose
    return id
  }
}
```

The `Session` struct

```
struct Session: TimelineItem, Decodable, Equatable {
  let id: Int
  let type: TimelineItemType = .Session
  let startDate: NSDate
  let name: String
  let syllabus: String
  let speaker: Speaker
  let language: String
  let room: String
  let duration: Int

  init?(json: JSON) {
    guard let id: Int = "id" <~~ json,
      let type: TimelineItemType = "type" <~~ json,
      let startDate: NSDate = Decoder.decodeDateISO8601("startDate")(json),
      let name: String = "name" <~~ json,
      let speaker: Speaker = "speaker" <~~ json,
      let syllabus: String = "syllabus" <~~ json,
      let language: String = "language" <~~ json,
      let room: String = "room" <~~ json,
      let duration: Int = "duration" <~~ json where type == .Session else {
        return nil
    }
    self.id = id
    self.startDate = startDate
    self.name = name
    self.speaker = speaker
    self.syllabus = syllabus
    self.language = language
    self.room = room
    self.duration = duration
  }
}
```

And finally the code I tried to split my Array:

```
func timelineFromItems(timelineItems: [TimelineItem]) -> [[Header: [Session]]]? {

    let slicedSessions = timelineItems.split { $0 is Header }
    let sessions = Array(slicedSessions)
    let headers = timelineItems.filter { $0.type == .Header }
    var timeline = [[Header: [Session]]]()
    // HOW TO FILL THE TIMELINE ??
}
```

**HOW TO FILL THE TIMELINE ?**

Answer (score 1):

I reduce this example by removing all not necessary information

```
protocol P {}
struct A: P, Hashable {
    var i:Int
    var hashValue: Int { return i }
}
func ==(lhs: A, rhs: A)->Bool {
    return lhs.i == rhs.i
}
struct B: P {
    var i:Int
}

// your current data
let arr:[P] = [A(i: 1),B(i: 1),B(i: 2), A(i: 2), B(i: 3), B(i: 4), B(i: 5)]
```

function which transforms your data to required format

```
func foo(arr: [P])->[[A:[B]]]? {

    var dict:[A:[B]] = [:]
    var arrb:[B] = []
    let arrk:[A] = arr.filter { $0 is A }.map { $0 as! A }
    guard var key = arr[0] as? A else { return nil }

    arr.forEach { (p) in

        if let a = p as? A {
            dict[key] = arrb
            arrb = []
            key = a
        }
        if let b = p as? B {
            arrb.append(b)
        }
    }
    dict[key] = arrb
    var arrr:[[A:[B]]] = []
    arrk.forEach { (a) in
        if let arrb = dict[a] {
            arrr.append([a:arrb])
        }
    }
    return arrr
}
```

now the resulting array conforms to your requirements (I hope :-))

```
if let result = foo(arr) {
    print(result) // [[A(i: 1): [B(i: 1), B(i: 2)]], [A(i: 2): [B(i: 3), B(i: 4), B(i: 5)]]]
}
```

another test data

```
let arr:[P] = [A(i: 1),B(i: 1),B(i: 2), A(i: 2), A(i: 3), B(i: 3)]
```

gives you

```
[[A(i: 1): [B(i: 1), B(i: 2)]], [A(i: 2): []], [A(i: 3): [B(i: 3)]]]
```

so, it works even though no B follows A

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any obstacle in filling the timeline, here is how I would do it:

```
func timelineFromItems(timelineItems: [TimelineItem]) -> [[Header: [Session]]]? {

    let slicedSessions = timelineItems.split { $0 is Header }
    let sessions = Array(slicedSessions)
    let headers = timelineItems.filter { $0.type == .Header }
    var timeline = [[Header: [Session]]]()

    if sessions.count == headers.count { // Check to be sure you have as much header as sessions
        for (index, value) in headers.enumerate() {
            let dictionary = [value: sessions.getElement(index)]
            timeline.append(dictionary)
        }
    }

    return timeline
}
```

Comment: There is a missing opening `{` in the `for` statement.

Comment: Juste tried your solution which seems really closed to what I would like to have. But I have a compile error: `Ambiguous reference to subscript` in `sessions[index]`.

Comment: Do you need the let sessions = Array (slicedSessions) ? Does it work if you remove it and replace sessions[index] by slicedSessions[index] ?

Comment: Same issue occurs with 'slicedSessions'

Comment: Alternatively it may ne possible to use sessions.objectAtÎdex(index) although I don't know if that works in Swift

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103810/discussion-between-gl0ub1l-and-the-tom).

Comment: sessions.getElement(index) should work, I updated the code accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You can actually go with something as simple as:

```
func deserialize(input: [TimelineItem]) -> [Header: [Session]] {
    var result = [Header: [Session]]()

    var latestHeader: Header! = nil

    input.forEach() {
        if let header = $0 as? Header {
            latestHeader = header
            result[header] = []
        } else if let session = $0 as? Session {
            result[latestHeader]!.append(session)
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

**UPD**

Not as simple, but still concise (above produces the dictionary with `[Session]` as elements, while as @user3441734 pointed out you need an array of single-element dictionaries):

```
func deserialize(input: [TimelineItem]) -> [[Header: [Session]]] {
    var result = [[Header: [Session]]]()

    var latestHeader: Header? = nil

    input.forEach() {
        if let header = $0 as? Header {
            latestHeader = header
            result.append([header: []])
        } else if let session = $0 as? Session, let header = latestHeader {
            var headerDict = result.popLast()!
            headerDict[header]!.append(session)
            result.append(headerDict)
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Comment: your result is dictionary, so unordered collection. my first attempt was the same, before i realized, that he needs ordered collection / array of dictionaries, where the dictionary has only one key and one associated value (array) / ... Array<[Header:[Session]]>

Comment: Oh, yes.  My bad.  So he needs an array of single-element dictionaries.  Let me tweak the code then.

Comment: i did it, see my answer. Still the code is 'not the best', as you can see, it works as expected :-)

Comment: now, it works! it is much cleaner, as my own approach! can you compare it with my own, two faze approach, from the perspective of effectiveness? by the way, if for some reason TimeLineItem[0] is not Header, the result just ignore it and all following Session(s) until next Header ... That could be fine, I just note that for clarification.

Comment: Well, yes.  The code is just a sketch to demonstrate the idea.  OP should adjust it for a particular need.

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to all of you, I managed to fit my need with the code below:

```

```
typealias Section = [header: Header, sessions: [TimelineItem]]

private static func groupBySection(timelineItems: [TimelineItem]) -> [Section]? {
    let slicedSessions = timelineItems.split { $0.type == .Header }
    let headers = timelineItems.filter { $0.type == .Header }
    var timeline = [Section]()

    for (index, value) in headers.enumerate() {
      guard index < slicedSessions.count else {
        break
      }

      let sessionIndex = slicedSessions.startIndex.advancedBy(index)
      let arraySessions = Array(slicedSessions[sessionIndex])
      let header = value as! Header
      let section = (header: header, sessions: arraySessions)
      timeline.append(section)
    }
    return timeline.count > 0 ? timeline : nil
  }
```

```